# method error on joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hey I hope you can give me advise on my problem. I got a Course Model, a CourseEnrollment Model and a User Model. In the Course index view it lists all the courses. I got a link_to to join a course. I want to create a new entry on the course_enrollments table.

```
link_to 'join', current_user.course_enrollments.create(:course_id => course,:user_id => current_user)
```

In my course_enrollments_controller I have:

```
def create
@course_enrollment = CourseEnrollment.new(params[:course_id, :user_id])
end
```

thx for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are really mixing things up here. You are linking to the return value of the create method of a model but I guess you want to link to the "create" action of a controller.

Maybe you should (re-?) read a guide or introduction on Rails first.

Comment: whats the difference between the create method of a controller and of a method?

Comment: Simply said the controller responds to your HTTP request while the model does not even know of it. Call the models in the controller. Maybe read something about MVC.

Comment: whats the right way? I read many articles, but I am stuck on this. dont understand... :(

Comment: "Call the models in the controller. Maybe read something about MVC." Start on something lower again.